# Detect Collision in Simple Space Invaders

Tags: java

Im using java to create a space invaders game but i seem to be having trouble detecting collisions, here is my game panel, we were given some sample code which i have added to. I have created different classes for each enemy which are extended from the enemy class.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{
    private Player player;
    private Enemy enemy;
    private Enemy mothership;
    private Enemy destroyer;
    private Enemy meteor;
    private int enemyNumber = 0;
    private int totalscore = 0;
    private boolean destroyerspawn = false;
    private boolean meteorspawn = false;
    private boolean mothershipstop = false;
    private boolean meteorstop = false;
    private boolean destroyerstop = false;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private ArrayList<Enemy> enemyList;
    Timer redrawTimer;

    public GamePanel()
    {
        // As above commented out until enemy classes have been made
        enemyList = new ArrayList<Enemy>();

        // This starts the time that controls how often the screen is redrawn 
        redrawTimer = new Timer(10, this);
    }

    // Method to start the game
    public void startGame(int width, int height)
    {
        // Create player
        player = new Player(width, height);
        // Create mothership
        mothership = new Mothership(width, height, 0, 0);
        // Create destroyer
        destroyer = new Destroyers(width, height, 0, 0);
        // Create meteor
        meteor = new Meteor(width, height, 0, 0);

        // Loop to create multiple enemies
        // Goes through y axis changing the enemy type at each increment
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            // Goes through x axis making 6 of each enemy type
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            {
                if(y == 0 || y == 3)
                {
                    enemy = new Martians(width, height, (x * 70), (y * 70));
                    enemyList.add(enemy);
                    enemyNumber++;
                }
                else if(y == 1 || y == 4)
                {
                    enemy = new Mercurians(width, height, (x * 70), (y * 70));
                    enemyList.add(enemy);
                    enemyNumber++;
                }
                else if(y == 2 || y == 5)
                {
                    enemy = new Venusians(width, height, (x * 70), (y * 70));
                    enemyList.add(enemy);
                    enemyNumber++;
                }
            }
        }

        // Starts draw timer
        redrawTimer.start();
    }

    // Method to pause the game
    public void pauseGame()
    {
        redrawTimer.restart();
    }

    // Handles the timer event, so this method repeats based on the interval set in your timer 
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {   
        this.revalidate();
        // Causes the screen to be redrawn
        this.repaint();
    }

    // Our paint component method that draws every thing we need to the screen
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {

        // This line ensures that every that would usually be drawn by a panel is
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Clear the screen
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

        if(player!= null && player.isActive())
        {
            // Draw the player
            player.draw(g);
        } 

        // If statement that stops this code running once it's deactivated once
        if (mothershipstop == false)
        {
            // If there are no enemies left
            if (enemyNumber == 0)
            {
                if(mothership!= null && mothership.isActive())
                {
                    // Draw and move the mothership
                    mothership.draw(g);
                    mothership.Move();
                }

                // Detects whether there's been a collision
                for (int b = 0; b < player.getBulletCount(); b++)
                {
                    // Collision detection for bullet
                    player.getBullet(b).detectCollision(mothership);
                }

                if (player.isActive() == true && mothership.isActive())
                {
                    // Collision detection for player
                    player.detectCollision(mothership);     
                }           
            }
        }

        // If statement that stops this code running once it's deactivated once
        if (destroyerstop == false)
        {
            // Each tick will have a 1 in 1000 chance of spawning a destroyer 
            if (random.nextInt(1000) == 1)
            {
                destroyerspawn = true;
            }
            // If the random integer got activated, destroyer spawns
            if (destroyerspawn == true && destroyer!= null && destroyer.isActive())
            {  
                // Draw and move the destroyer
                destroyer.draw(g);
                destroyer.Move();

                // Detects whether there's been a collision
                for (int b = 0; b < player.getBulletCount(); b++)
                {
                    // Collision detection for bullet
                    player.getBullet(b).detectCollision(destroyer);             
                }
            }
            else if (destroyer.isActive() == false)
            {
                destroyerstop = true;
                totalscore = totalscore + destroyer.GetScore();
            }
        }

        // If statement that stops this code running once it's deactivated once
        if (meteorstop == false)
        {
            // Each tick will have a 1 in 700 chance of spawning an asteroid 
            if (random.nextInt(700) == 1)
            {
                meteorspawn = true;
            }
            // If the random integer got activated, asteroid spawns
            if (meteorspawn == true && meteor!= null && meteor.isActive())
            {

                // Draw and move the asteroid
                meteor.draw(g);
                meteor.Move();

                // Detects whether there's been a collision
                for (int b = 0; b < player.getBulletCount(); b++)
                {
                    // Collision detection for bullet
                    player.getBullet(b).detectCollision(meteor);
                }

                if (player.isActive() == true && meteor.isActive())
                {
                    // Collision detection for player
                    player.detectCollision(meteor);
                }   
            }
            else if (meteor.isActive() == false)
            {
                meteorstop = true;
                totalscore = totalscore + meteor.GetScore();
            }
        }

        // Code to draw the enemy
        Iterator<Enemy> iterator = enemyList.iterator();

        // Loops to check each enemy
        while (iterator.hasNext()) 
        {
            // Checks the next enemy
            enemy = iterator.next();

            // If there's an enemy or active enemy
            if(enemy != null && enemy.isActive())
            {
                // Draw and move the enemy
                enemy.draw(g);
                enemy.Move();
            } // If non-existent enemy or is inactive
            else
            {
                // Get score
                totalscore = totalscore + enemy.GetScore();
                // Remove the enemy
                iterator.remove();
            }

            // If an enemy has been removed
            if (enemy.lives == 0)
            {
                // Decrement number of enemies
                enemyNumber--;
            }

            // Detects whether there's been a collision
            for (int b = 0; b < player.getBulletCount(); b++)
            {         
                // Collision detection for bullet
                player.getBullet(b).detectCollision(enemy);
            }

            if (player.isActive() == true && enemy.isActive())
            {
                // Collision detection for player

            }           
        }

        // Checks if game ends
        endGame();  

    }

    public void endGame()
    {
        if (player.isActive() == false)
        {
            // You lose
            System.out.println("Game over! You lose.");
            System.out.println("Your score is: " + totalscore);
            // Close game
            System.exit(ABORT);
        }else if (mothership.isActive() == false)
        {
            // You win
            totalscore = totalscore + mothership.GetScore(); 
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You win.");
            System.out.println("Your score is: " + totalscore);
            // Close game
            System.exit(ABORT);

        }

    }

    // Code here controls the key events
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) 
    {
        switch(event.getKeyCode())
        {
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: player.move(1); break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: player.move(-1); break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE: player.fire(); break;
        }   
    }


    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) 
    {

    }

}
```

n my bullet class there is a detect collision method that we have to fill in, i however have no clue how to do this. here is the code for the bullet class.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Bullet {

    private Point position;
    private int height, width;
    private BufferedImage img;
    private int speed = 20;
    private boolean active;


    public Bullet(Point playerPosition){

        //same as the player class this simply loads the image for the bullet.
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/playerbullet.jpg"));
            //System.out.println("***************OK*******************");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //System.out.println("***************CAN'T READ FILE*******************");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        height = img.getHeight();
        width = img.getWidth();

        //sets the bullet position we have to do a little offset wit the bullet image so our bullet appears in the (horizontal) centre of our player
        position = new Point(playerPosition.x - (width/2), playerPosition.y);

        active = true;
    }

    //draws the bullet
    public void draw(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(img, position.x, position.y, width, height, null);

    }

    //moves the bullet unless it has gone off the top of the screen in which case the bullet is destroyed
    public void move(){
        if(position.y < 0){
            destroy();
        }
        else{
            position.y-=speed;
        }

    }

    //sets the bullet as inactive
    public void destroy(){
        active = false;
    }

    //returns whether the bullet is active or not
    public boolean isActive(){
        return active;
    }

    //returns the bullets current position
    public Point getPosition() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    // this method will flag as an error until you create your enemy classes
    public void detectCollision(Enemy e)
    {

    }



}
```

Comment: So where is your problem? What part of the code does not work for you? What's the indication that your code does not work as desired?

Comment: player.detectCollision(mothership); 
The method detectCollision(Enemy) is undefined for the type Bullet

Comment: That error does not match the given line of code.

Comment: @NadirMahmood Are you sure that the error is not on this line `player.getBullet(b).detectCollision(mothership);`? Your error message suggests that.

Comment: vague problem definition & poorly worded question.

Comment: Apologies for the lack a clear question, i have now edited it for more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Rectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#createIntersection(java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D)) class in Java

There is a method called "createIntersection" which returns the Rectangle where 2 rectangles overlap. If that area is zero, there's no collision.

Inside your Bullet class, you stored the position, width and height. But in fact this tells that you are actually storing the "Rectangle". So, try to refactor your implementation and use Rectangle instead.

In the detectCollision() method, the parameter should be the Rectangle of the checking target (i.e. player). Then you can use the createIntersection() to check the overlapping area

Comment: Im sorry but you are talking to a beginner here, and that doesn't help me all that much haha

Comment: @NadirMahmood Nevertheless, beginner or not, it is a correct answer and you should go through the documentation for it.